# Handlebars: 3 Nested #each loops causing html table to iterate 10 times per row

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, handlebars.js

Below are my Handlebars `#each` loops. It is causing 100 table rows, when I am supposed to have only 10 table rows.

```
  {{#each data.genes}}
   {{#each obj}} 
    {{#each ../array}}
      <tr>

        <td class="td-trials">{{name}}</td>
        <td class="td-trials"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs={{@../key}}">{{@../key}}</a></td>
        <td class="td-trials">{{age}}</td>
        <td class="td-trials">{{../this}}</td>

      </tr>
    {{/each}}
   {{/each}}  
  {{/each}}`enter code here`
```

My data is structured as below. The data comes from an API. I passed it in an object in `res.render`, in my express `route`. I removed the actual data for simplicities sake.

`data.genes` is this whole object:

`obj` is `obj`

`array` is `array`

```
{ 
  _id: 5123ebd05482848222133e90,
  obj: { 
     NJ: 'Cherry Hill',
     PA: 'Philly',
     NY: 'Monticello'
  },
  __v: 0,
  user_id: [ 638e82d ],
  array: [ 
     { 
       name: 'George',
       age: '10'

     },
     { 
       name: 'Paul',
       age: '20'

     } 
  ]
}
```

The problem I am having is that the table elements are displaying 10 times each. `{{name}}` and `{{age}}` display a different `array`'s object `name` one after the other, then repeats, 10 times. The other two variables `{{../@key}}` and `{{../this}}` display the same `key` and `value` 10 times in a row, then it repeats 10 times. I only need 10 rows with no repeating data. Can someone tell me how to stop this from happening?

```
  <tr>

    <td class="td-trials">{{name}}</td>
    <td class="td-trials"><a target="_blank" href="={{@../key}}">{{@../key}}</a></td>
    <td class="td-trials">{{age}}</td>
    <td class="td-trials">{{../this}}</td>

  </tr>
```

Express route:

```
router.get('/tools/my-genes', function(req, res) {
 var data = {};

 SNPs.find({user_id: req.user._id}).then(function(result) {
  data.genes = result;
 })

 res.render('tools/gene_data', {
  data: data,
  layout: 'dash'
 });
});
```

Comment: I don't see `genes` in your data.

Comment: And you're going to need to explain what `obj` is. It doesn't look like it should be eached, but with such generic data as `key` and `value`, it's impossible to know what purpose it serves.

Comment: I removed the actual values for simplicities sake @76484

Comment: One would need to know what output you expect for the data you have specified in order to diagnose the problem. Please take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/etswt1qy/) and tell us if the output is as expected.

Comment: I updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/etswt1qy/#&togetherjs=rGTBiMf7sM) @76484